# Scraping with PHP DOMXpath: How do I scrape up until a particular tag?

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument, domxpath

I am trying to scrape a block of data that looks something like this:

```
<h2>...</h2>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<h2>...</h2>
<p>...</p>
...
```

What I am trying to do is to scrape data from a wiki page so that I can rebuild it in a way that looks something like this:

[image]

based on this:

[image]

I can get the headers by targeting the contents `div` which has a class. However, the texts beneath the headers do not have any ID or class. Using `query("//div[@id='mw-content-text']//p")`, all of the relevant `<p>` texts are extracted plus some irrelevant ones. Now I need to extract the specific data so that I can put the texts under the correct headings and I have no idea how.

Is it possible to scrape in a way such that we can target the `<p>...</p>` that comes after/before a `<h2>...</h2>` tag?

Update: sample site and code

http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Darkscale_Healer

```
<?php 

// Initialize a cURL session
$ch = curl_init("http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Darkscale_Healer");

// TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Perform a cURL session
$target = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom -> loadHTML($target);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$contents = $xpath -> query("//div[@id='mw-content-text']//p");//query("//ul//li//a//span[@class='toctext']/text()");

foreach($contents as $content) {
    echo $content -> nodeValue . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: maybe use `following-sibling`

Comment: do you have a sample site that you can share? and most importantly your codes

Comment: @Ghost Updated the post with a sample site and sample code.

Comment: my goodness what kind of structuring is this site using, not even a div which holds each paragraph. haha